# Высвобождение памяти

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти

Не могу найти где забываю высвободить память. Подскажите,пожалуйста.

```
class TData {
public:
    bool IsEmpty;
    int Key;
    char Value[65];

    TData();
    void Print();

};

class TVector {
private:
    size_t capacity;
public:
    TData *array;
    size_t size;
    TVector();
    TVector(const size_t &);
    size_t Size() const;
    size_t Capacity() const;
    void Push_back(const TData &);
    void CountingSort(TVector* vector);
    ~TVector();
};

TData::TData() {
    this->Key = 0;
}


void TData::Print() {
    printf("%d\t%s\n", this->Key, this->Value);
}

TVector::TVector() {
    size = 0;
    capacity = 1;
    array = new TData[capacity];
}

TVector::TVector(const size_t & sizeVector) {
    capacity = sizeVector;
    size = 0;
    array = new TData[sizeVector];
}

void TVector::Push_back(const TData &temp) {
    if (size == capacity) {
        capacity *= 2;
        TData *result = new TData[capacity];
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            result[index] = array[index];
        }
        delete[] array;
        this->array = result;
    }
    array[size++] = temp;
}


size_t TVector::Size() const {
    return size;
}

size_t TVector::Capacity() const {
    return capacity;
}

void TVector::CountingSort(TVector* vector) {
    int tmp[RANGE] = { 0 };
    TData *out = new TData[vector->Size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < vector->Size(); i++) {
        tmp[vector->array[i].Key]++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < RANGE; i++) {
        tmp[i] += tmp[i - 1];
    }
    for (int i = vector->Size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        out[--tmp[vector->array[i].Key]] = vector->array[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vector->Size(); ++i) {
        vector->array[i] = out[i];
    }
    delete[] out;
}



TVector::~TVector() {
    delete[] array;
}


int main(void) {

    TVector v;
    TData data;


    while (scanf("%d%s", &data.Key, data.Value) == 2) {
        v.Push_back(data);
    }

    if (v.Size() > 1) {
        v.CountingSort(&v);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v.Size(); ++i) {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", v.array[i].Key, v.array[i].Value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему вы уверены, что забыли?  Кстати, мне кажется, что стоит либо написать копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания, либо просто их удалить. Они-то тут не играют роли, но можно ведь потом и забыть :)

Comment: Когда прохожусь valgrind ловлю
`total heap usage: 3 allocs, 4 frees, 73,804 bytes allocated`
`still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks`

Comment: Забавно, что у вас освобождается вроде больше, чем выделяется... Я просто переписал `new` и `delete` с фиксацией действий - у меня что выделилось, то и освободилось...